# Transforming recursion into tail recursion?

Tags: prolog, exponentiation, logic-programming

I am trying to write a predicate that recursively finds the nth power of some number
[A^n = A * A^(n-1)] and uses the shortcut A^(2n) = A^n * A^n.

Here is the solution so far.

```
p(_,0,1):-!.
p(A,N,R):-N mod 2=0,!,N1=N/2,p(A,N1,R1),R=R1*R1.
p(A,N,R):-N1=N-1,p(A,N1,R1),R=R1*A.
```

Now I want to make this tail recursive. I can do tail for simple cases, such as factorials and power without the shortcut (by adding an accumulator), but this one is hard.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I think it's impossible. Waiting to see if somebody knows a way...

Comment: @CapelliC is it even possible to do factorial and power in a tail recursive fashion without an accumulator?

Comment: Initial question not clear: do you mean you don't want to use an accumulator at all, or is it that you can't figure out a way to incorporate your shortcut (A^2N = A^N*A^N) into the tail-recursive solution which can have an accumulator?

Comment: @Boris The latter. I know I HAVE to use an accumulator for tail recursion, just don't know how to incorporate the shortcut.

Comment: if you have a logarithmic algorithm, it is usually less urgent to convert the code into TR form. Maximum recursion stack depth is *not likely* to be breached (preventing a possibility of stack overflow is probably the only/main reason for trying to avoid linear recursion at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it is sort of possible after all, just start it from the other end:

```
pow(A,N,R) :-
    pow(A,N,A,1,R).

pow(_,N,R,N,R) :- !.
pow(A,N,Acc,M,R) :-
    M =< N div 2, !,
    M1 is M*2,
    NewAcc is Acc * Acc,
    pow(A,N,NewAcc,M1,R).
pow(A,N,Acc,M,R) :-
    M < N,
    M1 is M+1,
    NewAcc is A * Acc,
    pow(A,N,NewAcc,M1,R).
```

It applies the shortcut up to the highest power of 2 smaller than N, which is admittedly not the same as what your algorithm is doing.

Comment: It is the same after all, even the same order of multiplications, only that you start with A instead of A*1. Think about it: The multiplications in the original algorithm occur in the reverse order of the calls, which means that the results are aquired in order, for, say, N=5: 1, 1*A, (1*A)*(1*A), ((1*A)*(1*A)*(1*A)*(1*A)), ((1*A)*(1*A)*(1*A)*(1*A))*A. Precisely the same, in your algorithm you start with A, then square it as often as possible and multiply with A only at the last iteration.

Comment: @MikeHartl: you might be right, I'm not sure. Altogether this sort of algorithms are somewhat unnecessary in a language implementation that probably has a highly optimized built-in power function.

Comment: @Boris Thank you! Seems the same to me as well. It's just an exercise, I would probably never use self-written math algorithms in the real world application.

Comment: @user825089: Now that I thought about it, it is definitely not the same. For a power of 5 it happens to be the same, but for powers 2^(n)-1, for example, it is not. Try out A^7, or A^15!

Comment: @Boris: but this algorithm may still be useful in other algebras than the real numbers. Exponentiation by squaring can be easily adapted to produce strings, trees and other structures.

Comment: trying out `A^7`: OP: `A*( (A*(A^2))^2)` (4 mults); this answer: `((A^2)^2)*A*A*A` (5 mults) ; `A^15`: 15-14-7-6-3-2 vs 2-4-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15. So the OP algorithm performs at most `2*log2(n)` multiplications, but this algorithm performs `~ n/2` multiplications. *Not* an improvement. But you can have TR algo with log(n) steps: trail blaze your way down by halving, collecting the results in a list, and then go back up consulting the list to perform exactly same steps as OP algo would do (= Mike's answer). Or, collect all powers as you calc them here, and "knapsack" them in: 2-4-8-12-14-15.

Answer (score 2):

Boris is right in that what his algorithm does is not the same as the original one. But here is how you can reproduce it, if you really want to:

Observe that you can determine the order of the operations from the binary representation of the number. Let `N=7`, then binary `N=111`, denoted as `N=7~111`.

Now you see the scheme in your original algorithm:

```
N      Op     N'
7~111  Mul    6~110 (= zero last bit) 
6~110  Squ    3~011 (= shift right)
3~011  Mul    2~010 
2~010  Squ    1~001
1~001  Base
```

Considering that due to the recursive nature of the algorithm, these steps are carried out top-to-bottom, you get `Base - Squ - Mul - Squ - Mul = ((A*A)*A)*((A*A)*A))*A = A**7`

Contrast this to Boris' algorithm:

```
N      Op     N'
1~001  Squ    2~010 (=shift left)
2~010  Squ    4~100 (=shift left)
4~100  Mul    5~101 (=add one)
5~101  Mul    6~110 (=add one)
6~110  Mul    7~111 (=add one)
```

So this one does all the shifting first, while the original considers each bit except for the first of N, right to left, in turn, "queuing" (because of bottom-up) `Mul, Squ` if the bit is set or just `Squ` if it is unset.

To reproduce this behavior (which is more efficient, as you will never do more simple multiplications than squares), you could start with `N` in binary and do the following (here in general pseudocode, easy for you to translate into prolog):

```
Acc=A
for i in (reverse(tail(bits(N)))):
    Acc*=Acc
    if i==1:
       Acc*=A
```

This is for `N>=1`. `N=0` is a special case and must be treated separately.

I'm pretty sure this is correct. If you have doubts, then just think about your original algorithm: testing for `mod 2 == 0` is the same as testing if the last bit is zero. And if it is not, then substracting one is the same as zeroing out the last bit while doubling and halving is just shifting left or right in binary.

Comment: Thank you for these valuable insights!